# Build an object having nested entities.Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using Java 1.6

Scenario: 
I have an entity structure called 'pnr' which looks like this:

```
<pnr>
    <outbound>
        <travellers>
            <person>
                <name></name>
                <address></address>
            </person>
            <person>
                <name></name>
                <address></address>
            </person>
        </travellers>
        <segments>
            <segment>
                <from></from>
                <to></to>
                <date></date>
                <flight-details>
                    <flight-id></flight-id>
                </flight-details>
            </segment>

            <segment>
                <from></from>
                <to></to>
                <date></date>
                <flight-details>
                    <flight-id></flight-id>
                </flight-details>
            </segment>
        </segments>
    </outbound>

    <inbound>
        ...
    </inbound>
</pnr>
```

I want to build an object whose structure looks like the above XML.
I start with an object of class "Pnr" which looks like this:

```
class Pnr{
    Outbound outbound;
    Inbound inbound;
}

//Outbound
class Outbound{
    ...
}

//Inbound
class Inbound{
    ...
}
```

The nesting of entities follows and each entity is represented by a class.

Please suggest a design pattern to build the nested Pnr object.

I have gone through the builder pattern. 
But in my case:
1)  We dont have too many parameters which we are passing to any of the constructors.
2)  All the time we want the whole Pnr object to be built. So we dont require a number of constructors with different parameter list.

But I have to handle building of the nested entities effectively.
Should I still go with builder pattern ?

If not please suggest which design pattern will be suitable for such a case.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, why can't you just pass an `Inbound` and `Outbound` object to the `Pnr` constructor?

Comment: *"I need to build the next google. Which design pattern solves that problem, for me?"* No, it doesn't work like that. Design patterns aren't algorithms, they are recommendations to structure your program. I recommend taking a look at JAXB BTW. You can even generate your object structure from a xsd schema using xjc...

Comment: @JornVernee I can do that. But then I have to write a method to build, say Inbound object. Like: buildInbound() which internally calls buildTravellers() which in-turn calls buildPerson() which again should call buildAddress(). I can put all these methods in a helper class and proceed. But is there a better way ?

Comment: When you want to map something like this to the type safe environment of Java, there is always going to be boilerplate. You could also go for a generic implementation with nodes, where you call `getAttribute`, which might or might not return a value. I'd choose to do the extra work, as long as the model doesn't change frequently. The end result is much more usable. Also, all these build methods can just be constructor calls, builders are useful when you have a lot of optional constructor parameters, but you seem to imply that you don't.

Comment: Does every one of your entities (Pnr, Inbound, Outbound, etc) have any behaviour, or are they merely data structures? Are they expected to have behaviour in the future?

Comment: No they merely hold the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting things wrong here. The layout of serialized data (for example when writing information into XML files) shouldn't affect the design of your **classes** at all.

Example: in your XML you got those categories "inbound" and "outbound". Do you really need them in your **object model**; meaning: do you really want to "fix" that within your class structure?

What I am saying is: focus on the design of your **object model**. There you define entities, classes; and more specifically: there you define the reasonable properties of your objects.

And then, when you came up with a sufficient model, then you think about transformations that write/read from XML.

Like in: you might be using a SAX parser; and when that parser comes along "person" information, it collects the required information and creates a single Person object. And then, the next layer might decide to add the "n" Person objects that were created into some kind of collection that makes up the "travelers". But maybe travelers doesn't need to be a class; probably it is just a simple `List<Person>` instead.

Long story short: you got things backwards. You don't develop your object model based on some XML schema. To the contrary!

Comment: I have given the XML structure just to explain the fact that I have a nested composition of objects. I am not using any parser.

Comment: I have given the XML structure just to explain the fact that I have a nested composition of objects. I am not using any parser. I already have all the required data. Nested objects can be built by putting all the relevant methods in one class. For example: buildOutbound() will  build my outBound object, which inturn calls the populateTravellers()method, which iterates through travellers and calls in-turn buildTraveller() which in-turn calls buildAddress() etc.. I can put all these methods in one class itself and proceed with building the Pnr object. But is there a neater way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Decorator Pattern? Not sure we need to create so many entities though in your case. But if the entities have to be subclassed as you said, we can use Decorator Pattern

However, SAX parser should be used ideally with entities like Person, FlightDetails and one class having list of these as elements. Refer http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax-example.html for example